# arraylist element comapring by index

Tags: java, arraylist, indexing, comparison

I am trying to compare `List<ArrayList<String>>`

here is my code:

```
    List<ArrayList<String>> storeStatusAfterAssign = storeManagerPage.getMaterialStatus();
    System.out.println(storeStatusAfterAssign);
```

giving me output:

```
[[Concrete Fabric, Universal Store, Pending, , Pending], [Wooden Beam, Office Admin, , Pending, Pending], [Regular Concrete, Universal Store, Pending, , Pending], [Fiber Glass, Office Admin, , Pending, Pending]]
```

Now I need to compare arraylist element like  if in first array of list second index is  **Universal Store** then  third index should be **Pending** And if   second index is  **Office Admin** then third index should be **blank** and forth index should **Pending** check in each list

Any one have any suggestion how i can achieve this

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure how the comparison between `storeStatusBeforeAssign` and `storeStatusAfterAssign` is suppose to be done. According to your current describtion it seems that the comparision is only to take place between the `ArrayList`s in `storeStatusAfterAssign`. Could you edit your question and clarify exactly what you want and which comparisions are to be done. Both between `storeStatusBeforeAssign` `storeStatusAfterAssign`  and in the `List`s themseleves.

Comment: I have edited question you were right

Answer (score 0):

This is a method that returns true if every condition you describied is filled for every `ArrayList`

```
public boolean checkList(List<ArrayList<String>> list) {
    
    boolean returnValue = true;
    for(ArrayList<String> arrayList : list) { //loop through every ArrayList in List
         if(arrayList.get(1) == "Universal Store") { //check if second index is Universal Store
              returnValue = (arrayList.get(2) == "Pending"); //set returnValue to true only if third index is Pending
         }
         else if(arrayList.get(1) == "Office Admin") {//check if second index is Office Admin
              returnValue = ((arrayList.get(2) == "") && (arrayList.get(3) == "Pending")) //set returnValue to true only if third index is blank and fourth index is Pending
         }
         if(!returnValue) { //check for each iteration if returnValue is false, if it is return false since then one ArrayList do not fill the conditions
            return false;
         }
    }
    return true; //return true if all ArrayLists fill the conditions
}
```

This Java program gives the expected output

```
public class Main {

    private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> s1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Concrete Fabric","Universal Store", "Pending", "", "Pending"));
        ArrayList<String> s2 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Wooden Beam", "Office Admin", "", "Pending", "Pending"));
        ArrayList<String> s3 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Regular Concrete", "Universal Store", "Pending","", "Pending"));
        ArrayList<String> s4 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Fiber Glass", "Office Admin","" , "Pending", "Pending"));

        List<ArrayList<String>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        
        list.add(s1);
        list.add(s2);
        list.add(s3);
        list.add(s4);

        
        System.out.println(checkList(list));
    }
    
    public static boolean checkList(List<ArrayList<String>> list) {
        
        boolean returnValue = true;
        for(ArrayList<String> arrayList : list) { //loop through every ArrayList in List
             if(arrayList.get(1) == "Universal Store") { //check if second index is Universal Store
                  returnValue = (arrayList.get(2) == "Pending"); //set returnValue to true only if third index is Pending
             }
             else if(arrayList.get(1) == "Office Admin") {//check if second index is Office Admin
                  returnValue = ((arrayList.get(2) == "") && (arrayList.get(3) == "Pending")); //set returnValue to true only if third index is blank and fourth index is Pending
             }
             if(!returnValue) { //check for each iteration if returnValue is false, if it is return false since then one ArrayList do not fill the conditions
                return false;
             }
        }
        return true; //return true if all ArrayLists fill the conditions
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @MarkusAnd  sorry for delay but we have weekend off in office so can't check and reply. now i checked your code but its not checking any if condition and always return true. even i change value intentionally to get false  but still its giving true

Comment: @ddjadav No worries. I am not sure I follow, what do you mean my code is not checking and if condotions? My code first check if the current `ArrayList` have "Universal Store" or "Office Admin" at index 1 and thereafter checks if the following index values meet the condition you stated in your question. This is done the lines `returnValue = (arrayList.get(2) == "Pending");` and `returnValue = ((arrayList.get(2) == "") && (arrayList.get(3) == "Pending"))`. And I do not understand what you mean that the code always return true? If I run it with your `Arraylist`s I only get `true` if it should.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more what you mean?

Comment: @ MarkusAnd thanks for your time.  I mean this line '''returnValue = (arrayList.get(2) == "Pending");''' when i change value from 'Accep't insted of 'Pending'still its returning 'true'

Comment: value from "Pending" to " "(empty string) still return true; when i debug its i show its not go inside condition to execute conditional statement even if condition is true. if condition is true its should go in side condition to check further.

Comment: I suspect that something is wrong in your `ArrayList`s. Do the `ArrayList`s contain the exact string "Universal Store" and "Office Admin"? If it does the code will go in the `if` statements if the strings are at index 1. I suspect that your `ArrayList`s do not contain the **exact same** strings that you posted in your question, maybe you can post your `ArrayList`s as a comment below?

Comment: i have posted exact `ArrayList` which i get output but still does same

Comment: I have edited my answer to give you my program that I am running. When I run this `true` is only given when it is expected to.